# how to Show/Hide ngx-boostrap popover using ngIf

Tags: angular, popover, ngx-bootstrap

I am using [ngx-bootsrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/) popover in angular 5. It's working fine when clicking the div tag, how can I activate the popover using `*ngIf`?

I tried using `*ngIf` this way but it's not working:

```html
<div *ngIf="true" 
    popover="today is very bad day" 
    placement="right"> Popover on right
</div>
```

Any help and/or suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: could you use your exact code?  are you getting any errors in the console?  are you having  problems hiding it or showing it?

Comment: no error its working like onclick not like ngif and isOpen="false" is not working

Comment: can you share your code ? @JBoothUA

Comment: Try `<div *ngIf="true"><div popover="today is very bad day" placement="righ" Popover on right
</div></div>`

Comment: this working like normal https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkw9mz-ndzt4u?file=app%2Ffour-directions.html

Comment: you want to show and hide popover based on some condition?

Comment: yes like ngif ..

Answer (score 2):

popover is a directive which will impact an element like button, div etc.
If you are trying to use *ngIf then you are trying to impact the element not the directive.

But if you are trying to disable popover on certain condition, then use isOpen property of popover and keep it's value false. your popover will not appear.

**checkout the exact example for your need** 
https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/popover#trigger-by-isopen-property

and as others have mentioned if you share your code then it will be helpful to provide more accurate answer.